# Pandas timestamp time mean

Tags: python, pandas

Input

```
Tech ID |   4th April'22       |       3rd April'22     |    2nd April'22   
123     | 2022-04-04 05:03:00  |   2022-04-03 05:08:00  |  2022-04-02 05:10:00  
345     | 2022-04-04 05:37:00  |   2022-04-03 05:18:00  |  2022-04-02 05:12:00   
678     | 2022-04-04 05:42:00  |   2022-04-03 05:25:00  |  2022-04-02 05:30:00   
901     | 2022-04-04 05:48:00  |   2022-04-03 05:45:00  |  2022-04-02 04:08:00  
367     | 2022-04-04 05:32:00  |   2022-04-03 06:08:00  |  2022-04-02 06:08:00
```

Output

```
Tech ID |    4th April'22      |        3rd April'22    |     2nd April'22     |   Mean  
123     | 2022-04-04 05:03:00  |   2022-04-03 05:08:00  |  2022-04-02 05:10:00 |  result  
345     | 2022-04-04 05:37:00  |   2022-04-03 05:18:00  |  2022-04-02 05:12:00 |  result  
678     | 2022-04-04 05:42:00  |   2022-04-03 05:25:00  |  2022-04-02 05:30:00 |  result  
901     | 2022-04-04 05:48:00  |   2022-04-03 05:45:00  |  2022-04-02 04:08:00 |  result  
367     | 2022-04-04 05:32:00  |   2022-04-03 06:08:00  |  2022-04-02 06:08:00 |  result
```

Comment: What would be the explicit result?

Comment: try `df[df.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).mean(),axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Pandas that you are using, you may be able to use the `Dataframe.mean` method to determine the mean across the rows.

You will need to set `numeric_only` to `False` per the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

> numeric_only: bool, default None
> Include only float, int, boolean columns. If None, will attempt to use everything, >then use only numeric data. Not implemented for Series.

```
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1,numeric_only=False)
```

This works for me using pandas 1.3.4 assuming the dtype of the 3 source columns are all datetime64[ns]